# typescript how comparison on two classes works

Tags: typescript

i created the exact same class in two folders `a` and `b`

```
export class Test {
  constructor() {}
  val(): string {
    return 'I am some test'
  }
}
```

When I now compare those two classes, I get `false`. But how can this be, they are exactly the same ?!

```
import {Test} from './a/test';
import {Test as Test2} from './b/test';

console.log(Test === Test2) // => false;
```

How does javscript know they are different ?!

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rjlacb?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

It always return false because two class is a different point. It is the same as comparing two object https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/